# Why my simple ajax code does not work?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Can anyone help me understand why the code does not work?

Its not change the text in the div to the text that the member write.

And sorry in advance for my English, my English teacher apparently did't do a good job... =/

the first page:

```
<script>
function showUser()
{
var str = document.forms["myForm"]["users"].value;
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","act2.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return showUser()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="users">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

the second page (act2.php): *(corrected the name)*

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

echo "$q";
?>
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Don't know why people use plain Javascript instead of jQuery, for example. Cross-browser solution, and easy as `$.post(url, { key: value }, function(response) { alert(response); });`

Comment: Its not change the text in the div to the text that the member write. and its not show any eror.

Comment: @devdRew Why on earth should a load a bloated framework just to do a simple ajaxcall?

Comment: @Christoph you mean all that 91.1KB of data? Yes, thats huge. Did you thought about how much time you save when using the framework?

Comment: I'm not against usage of a framework, I'm against people refusing to use their brains and let others do the work for them just because they are too lazy. Go ahead and use a framework but only if you at least once tried to do the same without framework. Only then you will get a real understanding of the language itself. (I didn't want to imply that you are such a person, but infact their are many people, even "professionals" who don't know the real difference between javascript and jQuery)

Comment: @Christoph, agree. But what if I say... Have you ever tried to made a smartphone, or TV, or anything else? There is no need to understand how it all works on the low-level, but you should know at least basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function needs to return false to prevent the default action of the form, otherwise your form will be submitted (which *is* the default action).

simply add a `return false` at the end of your code.

```
function showUser(){

   // ...
   xmlhttp.send();

   // prevents the default action (the submit from your form)
   return false;

}
```

or:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="showUser();return false;" method="post">
```

Also you can safely drop the IE5/6 compat code.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
```

simply becomes:

```
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
```

The `var` in front is pretty important, otherwise `xmlhttp` will become a member of the global object instead of a scoped variable.

Answer (score 1):

The file specified in this line

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","act2.php?q="+str,true);
```

is **act2.php**, but according to your post, you're looking for **ajax2.php**, could that be it?

Comment: No it is not the problem, I was wrong when I wrote the name of the file just in this post. the real name of the file is act2.php

Answer (score 1):

You have simply forgotten to "return false" in the showUser method, the form will post as usual before the Ajax call is made

**edit:**
To clarify, in the onsubmit you have return showUser(), the the showUser method never returns a value, to stop the browser from posting the form. Also, as suggested by other posters, you imply the php file is named ajax2.php but the code actually tries to hit act2.php.

Also, using some sort of framework (jQuery is highly popular) is recommended.

Comment: I'm sorry but my English is not good and I can't seem to understand what you wrote me about the retun false. You can show me on the code what you said? I think it would help me understand you better. And I'm using ajax and not in jquary because I'm trying to learn

Comment: Why should I load an 80k framework just to do a plain ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Just to show how you can do the same with less pain and jQuery.

```
<form name="myForm" action="/act2.php">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<div id="txtHint"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
        // Link handler for submiting form
        .on('submit', 'form[name="myForm"]', function(e) {
            // Preventing original form submition
            e.preventDefault();

            // Send all data from form, to url from form's action attribute (/act2.php) and set received data to div with id txtHint
            $.get($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data, status, xhr) {
                $('#txtHint').html(data);
            });
        });
</script>
```